# How to add css class to a link where the target ends with any file suffix except .pdf

Tags: jquery

I'd like to add css class to a link where the target ends with any file suffix except .pdf or .jpg. I want to do it with jquery and probably with filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably do it with something like

```
$('a').filter(function (){return $(this).attr('target').indexOf('.pdf', $(this).attr('target').length - 4) === -1 && return $(this).attr('href').indexOf('.jpg', $(this).attr('target').length - 4) === -1});
```

Comment: I get an error code: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined.


It works, when I change 'target' to 'href' and '.length - 3' to '.length - 4' (because there are 4 characters in '.pdf')

Here is the whole code
    $('a').filter(function (){
        return $(this).attr('href').indexOf('.pdf', $(this).attr('href').length - 4) === -1
    })

Comment: you're probably right, I did not test my code. I will edit my answer for future references